# Retrieving rows randomly in pl/sql query

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

I have a table (`t1`). I know how to retrieve percentage of set randomly.

What I want is to insert 30% of randomly selected rows into `t2`, and insert remaining 70% into table `t3`.

Is there any other way except inserting 30% into table `t2` and than compare `t2` with `t1` and insert into `t3`? This method is not good for me since table is huge.

ps. oracle version - 11g

Comment: Sorry for nitpicking, but there is no such thing as a PL/SQL query.  PL/SQL is a procedural language. Your query is probably just SQL.  It wouldn't hurt if you showed the query btw.

Comment: How huge is "huge"? How many rows (order of magnitude)?

Comment: around 350M etnries

Answer (score 2):

Look into [ora_hash](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B12037_01/server.101/b10759/functions097.htm). Generate a hash using the table's PK (or some similar column combination) with a bucket of 9, and those with a 0-6 go in one table, and those with 7,8 or 9 go in another.

Answer (score 2):

would an insert all work?   here is one I did with the HR employees table so I ordered by random and took 30 percent of them. those ones got an indicator of one. I did a union all on the whole table and give it an indicator of 0.  I took the max for the indicator then did an insert all. if the indicator is 1 into the first table otherwise the remaining 70% into the second.

```
INSERT ALL
  WHEN (table_one_ind = 1) THEN
INTO table_one
  (
    employee_id,
    first_name,
    last_name,
    email,
    hire_date,
    job_id
  )
  VALUES
  (
    employee_id,
    first_name,
    last_name,
    email,
    hire_date,
    job_id
  )
  ELSE
INTO table_two
  (
    employee_id,
    first_name,
    last_name,
    email,
    hire_date,
    job_id
  )
  VALUES
  (
    employee_id,
    first_name,
    last_name,
    email,
    hire_date,
    job_id
  )
SELECT MAX (table_one_ind) table_one_ind,
  employee_id,
  first_name,
  last_name,
  email,
  hire_date,
  job_id
FROM
  (SELECT t.*,
    1 AS table_one_ind
  FROM
    ( SELECT * FROM employees ORDER BY dbms_random.value
    ) t
  WHERE rownum <=
    ( SELECT ceil(COUNT(*)*.3) FROM employees
    )
  UNION ALL
  SELECT t.*, 0 FROM employees t
  )
GROUP BY employee_id,
  first_name,
  last_name,
  email,
  hire_date,
  job_id
```